# Change fontSize and text in tag using only one JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to change the `fontSize` and `innerText` using the same JavaScript function. I've changed the `fontSize`, but I also want to change the text inside the `<h3>` tag with the same JavaScript function. Is that possible?

```
<h3 id="h3_heading">This is H3 HEADING Click Below Button to Change Font  Size</h3>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('h3_heading').style.fontSize ='72px'"">
    Click me to change font size and Written Text Inside H3 Tag
</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use `.onclick` or `.addEventListener()` at `javascript`. Is requirement to use event attribute `onclick`?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking interest in my question!

@guest271314 Yes I want to use onclick function only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure is, you'll need to change your onclick to point to a function in your javascript code i.e.

```
<script>
function changeFontSize(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.style.fontSize = '72px';
    element.innerText = 'Text you want here';
}
</script>
```

Your onclick would change to `onclick="changeFontSize('h3_heading')"`

Comment: No problem!  Good luck on your journey into web development.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed that second " at the end of your event and it works. Additionally look at the rewritten onclick event for changing HTML.

```html
<h3 id="h3_heading">This is H3 HEADING Click Below Button to Change Font  Size</h3>

<button type="button" onclick="el = document.getElementById('h3_heading'); el.style.fontSize ='72px'; el.innerHTML = 'H3 changed!'">Click me to change font size and Written Text Inside H3 Tag</button>
```

Comment: You may want to note though, that using inline JS is a bad practice. It makes the code harder to read, it merges the concerns of functionality with structure, and isn't reusable.

Comment: Basically you're right. But today there are techniques breaking those rules. In React JS you often see inline JS and CSS.

Comment: Noted well friends :)